# How to access Mac OS X Kernel framework (mach) using JNA

Tags: java, macos, kernel, jna

I am attempting to write a Java class to access some Mac OS X memory statistics.  I have a working implementation parsing the string returned from vm_stat.   However, I am trying to use JNA to access the native code.

I've dug through the vm_stat source code enough to identify host_statistics64() as the function I need to call, but I can't seem to get to the library/framework which executes that.  The header files are located under /System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework.  However, unlike just about every other framework in that directory, there is no executable file, so the JNA code to access that framework throws a UnsatisfiedLinkError (image not found).

This is the code I'm using to attempt to access the library:

```
public interface Kernel extends Library {

    Kernel INSTANCE = (Kernel) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel", Kernel.class);

    // ... other code ...
}
```

The code works fine for a random selection of other frameworks in the directory (e.g., ApplicationServices.framework, etc.) as all of these appear to have a binary executable inside their directory structure.  Except for Kernel.

I've spent a few hours on Google trying to hunt down a solution, without success.  Any advice?

Comment: You might try passing a library name of `null`, which indicates to JNA to attempt to load symbols from the current process.

Comment: No dice with null but I did find another way to locate the library. It was in System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find out a command to run which tells me which libraries are loaded.  For Mac OS X the command I used was:

```
otool -L /usr/bin/vm_stat
```

This produced the following output:

> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)

So this worked like a charm:

```
SystemB INSTANCE = (SystemB) Native.loadLibrary("System.B",SystemB.class);
```

(The equivalent linux command is ldd.)